# JQuery animate adjacent divs to left and to right on clicking respective links

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, slide, direction

I have a fiddle here from an earlier thread on stack overflow that animates all divs from left to right: https://jsfiddle.net/Deepa_Thalikar/5kg0urx7/30/

**Javascript**

```
jQuery(function($) {

$('a.panel').click(function() {
    var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
        $other = $target.siblings('.active');

    if (!$target.hasClass('active')) {
        $other.each(function(index, self) {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.removeClass('active').animate({
                left: $this.width()
            }, 500);
        });

        $target.addClass('active').show().css({
            left: -($target.width())
        }).animate({
            left: 0
        }, 500);
    }
});
```

});

I would like to animate 3 divs by clicking on their respective links in such a manner that:

1. Target 2 should be the default on page load (straightforward!)
2. Clicking on link for Target 1 should always slide-in Target 1 from
   left to right
3. Clicking on link for Target 3 should always slide-in Target 3 from
   right to left

Tried but did not succeed. Please help! :) -Deepa